Checking if records in one table are linked to other tables
I have these data models:
class User(BaseModel, table=True):
   id: int

class Car(...):
   id: int

class Purchase(...):
   id: int
   user_id: int
   car_id: int

I want to create a query that checks (when committing a purchase); if the relevant user and car exists in MySQL with SQLAlchemy and Python
I have tried this statement:
user_ids= select(User.id)
car_ids = select(Car.id)
statement = select(Purchase).where(and_(
Purchase.user_id.in_(user_ids),
Purchase.car_id.in_(car_ids)
        ))
records = self._run_select_query(statement)

def _run_select_query(self, statement) -> list:
    with Session(self._engine) as session:
        results = session.exec(statement)
        return list(results.all())

But the returned records object is an empty list

user_id and car_id should be foreign keys. Then you don't use their IDs, you use variables that contain the User and Car objects, and SQLAlchemy will replace them with their IDs. When you do it this way, it's not possible for them not to exist.
